# How would I call the results of a returned object into a Hash/TreeMap? - Java

Tags: java

I've never used HashMap and am not quite certain how it works. I've got a MainMenu class, and from it the user chooses a number that will direct them to a separate class/method which requests information that will return to an object.

**I need** the user to enter a code that'll identify which row I've created (say the user enters QA in one request, and 400 in another...) I'll ask the user to enter QA400 and they'll see the entire line of information they entered earlier (after a bit of formatting.)

I'm just not sure how to take those variables and have them be printed out from a HashMap (or maybe I'm supposed to be using TreeMap? I've read its more organized?)

Here is a piece of my main menu, from inside the Switch Case.

```
                case 3:
                A8AirlineAircraftData.AddAirline(sc);
                continue;
            case 4:
                A8FlightData.AddFlight(sc);
                continue;
```

The user presses 3 and is then redirected to:

```
public class A8AirlineAircraftData {

private String airName; //these are all showing a warning saying 'Field ____ can be final'
private String airCode;
private String airCraft;
private int firstClass;
private int busiClass;
private int econClass;

public A8AirlineAircraftData(String airName, String airCode, String airCraft, int firstClass, int busiClass, int econClass) {
    this.airName = airName;
    this.airCode = airCode;
    this.airCraft = airCraft;
    this.firstClass = firstClass;
    this.busiClass = busiClass;
    this.econClass = econClass;
} 

public static A8AirlineAircraftData AddAirline(Scanner sc) {
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Airline name:");
    String airName = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the Airline code:");
    String airCode = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Delta Aircraft:");
    String airCraft = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the first class seat capacity:");
    int firstClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the business class seat capacity:");
    int busiClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the economy class seat capacity:");
    int econClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Airline name: " + airName);
    System.out.println("Airline code: " + airCode);
    System.out.println("Delta Aircraft: " + airCraft);
    //Splitting the first word from the rest of the string
    String arr[] = airCraft.split(" ", 2);
    String firstWord = arr[0];
    System.out.println(firstWord + " first class seat capacity: " + firstClass);
    System.out.println(firstWord + " business class seat capacity: " + busiClass);
    System.out.println(firstWord + " economy class seat capacity: " + econClass);
    //Airline object
    A8AirlineAircraftData airline = new A8AirlineAircraftData(airName, airCode, airCraft, firstClass, busiClass, econClass);
    System.out.println(airName + " successfully added. Press Enter to continue.");
    sc.nextLine();
    sc.nextLine();//Press Enter to continue 
    return airline;
```

I'd like the end-result to look like to simply restate the "airline" object from the main menu, or anywhere... I just am not sure where to begin with creating that.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: A Hashmap maps one object to another using a hashfunction. Hashmap<Key, Value>   use map.get(key) to return the object key maps to. I didn't really understand your question but hopefully that helps you a little.

Comment: If you want to simply restate the "airline" object from the main menu, then you **should** create an `Airline` object. Not a `Map` (`Hash`, `Tree`, or other).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch how would I begin to create this? I'm very inexperienced in Java I apologize.

Comment: @SamK9  could one end of the key be typed in by the User to match with data that was input before?

Comment: `new A8AirlineAircraftData(airName, airCode, airCraft, firstClass, busiClass, econClass);` looks reasonable enough. Add a `toString` there (to the class `A8AirlineAircraftData`). And rename it to `Airline`.

Comment: so you only want one part of your key to be inputted by the user not the whole key? If you want to do that and you are  using a String as the key just concatenate the two strings into one String then use that as the key

Comment: @ElliottFrisch where should toString be created? and rename 'airline' to 'Airline'? Oh okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to catch the returned object, i.e. the airline object in your case, in the main menu.

```
case 3: 
    A8AirlineAircraftData airline = A8AirlineAircraftData.AddAirline(sc);
    /*do something with the airline*/
    continue;
```

Comment: I tried to run this like System.out.println(airline) using that method and the output was: a8airlineflightschedule.A8AirlineAircraftData@15e6e48b

Comment: You have to add a toString() method in A8AirlineAircraftData.`public String toString(){return airName+airCode;}`

Comment: would you be able to show me an example of how I might do this? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: add this piece of code `public String toString(){return "airname is:" + airName + ", aircode is: "+airCode;}` to A8AirlineAircraftData class. Then use `System.out.println(airline.toString());`